# Syntax error on the onclick for input type button html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Can some one just help me out?
I get a syntax error on the two single quotes for javascript:window.location=

here my code:

```
 <input type="button" value="<%: Html.Resource(Resources.Global.Button.Reject);%>" onclick="javascript:window.location='<%: Url.Action("RejectUser", "Recommend", new { area = "Users"} ) %>';"/>
```

when I hover over the single quote it tells me unterminated string constant

is it a case of i cannot do this for input type button?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have javascript variable and function instead..

```
<script>
   var url = '<%: Url.Action("RejectUser", "Recommend", new { area = "Users"} ) %>';
   function fun(){
      window.location=url;
   }
</script>


<input type="button" value="<%: Html.Resource(Resources.Global.Button.Reject);%>" onclick="javascript:fun();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
onclick="javascript:window.location=\"<%: Url.Action(\"RejectUser\", \"Recommend\", new { area = \"Users\"} ) %>\";"
```